# Bitcoin wallet address format representation

Tags: address, address-generation

I want to send coins from my ether wallet to another bitcoin wallet that I have got. 
I entered my bitcoin wallet receiving address, but MyEtherWallet transaction convert it to another address format that starts with '0x' and I think it's hexadcimal.

How can I know for sure that this address is actually related to the address that I typed??
I am looking for external generator to verify myself that the receiving address that my boitcoin wallet displayed turned into the hexadecimal code they show

Comment: MyEtherWallet is a wallet for ETH/ETC and ERC20 tokens. You can't send   coins from MEW to a Bitcoin wallet. Or are you asking for something else?

Comment: Yes I can. It's called 'Swap'. Anyone else want to try to answer me?

Comment: You should rephrase your question then, there is a big difference between send and exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to transact with two different types of cryptocurrency.

You cannot send/receive Bitcoin from an Ethereum wallet and vice versa.

Comment: I am trying to convert and transfer coins from my ether wallet to my bitcoin wallet. This is functionality that MyEtherWallet provides. But that's not my question. I am asking about bitcoin address different format representation and how to convert from one format to another REGARDLESS my ether wallet.